# File Saving on iOS with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, phonegap-build, jspdf

I'm trying to create a app with `phonegap` that generates a pdf file and stores it on a iPad. On the emulators it actually works although on the iPad it doesn't do anything and I cant get a error to know what is going on.

```
function exportPDF() {
                 $(this).scrollTop(0);
                 $("#loading").show();
                 var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'px', 'legal');

                 doc.addHTML($('#container').get(0), 5, 5, {
                    'background': '#fff',
                    'width': 1110,
                }, function () {

                    $("#loading").hide();

                    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') == -1) {
                        doc.save("MyTurnToTalkSession.pdf");
                    } else {
                        doc.output('datauri');
                    }

                    exportRevert();

                });
            }
        });
```